# Как сохранить путь ключу в gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

Как сохранить путь ключу в gradle?  Проблема в том, что при вытаскивание проекта с mercurial на другом компе. Каждый раз указывать путь не удобно

```
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        keyAlias 'android'
        keyPassword '654321'
        storeFile file('/Users/Documents/android.jks')
        storePassword '123456'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто добавить debug - ключ в сам проект и в репозиторий